# Python subprocess.Popen pipe IO blocking unexpectedly

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ssh, pty

I am trying to use subprocess.Popen to control an ssh process and interact with it via pipes, like so:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-tt','LOGIN@HOSTNAME'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    (out_stdout,out_stderr)=p.communicate(timeout=10)
    if out_stderr:
        print(out_stderr)
    if not out_stdout:
        raise EOFError
    print(out_stdout)
```

This works fine without the '-tt' option to ssh. However the program I need to interact with on the remote side of the ssh breaks if there is no pseudo tty allocated, so I am forced to use it.

What this seems to do is that the p.communicate reads then block indefinitely (or until timeout), even if input is available.

I have rewritten this using lower level calls to io.read, select.select etc to avoid going through Popen.communicate. Select will actually return the file descriptor as ready, but a subsequent io.read to that file descriptor will also block. If I disable 'universal newlines' and set 'bufsize=0' in the Popen call it then works fine, but then I am forced to do binary/unicode conversion and line ending processing myself.

It's worth saying though, that disabling universal_newlines in the p.communicate version also blocks indefinitely, so its not just that.

Any advice on how I can get line buffered input working properly here without having to reimplement everything?

Comment: Can you run the remote program under `unbuffer` (a utility packaged with `expect`) to simulate a TTY?

Comment: BTW, generally speaking, this is the wrong way to run a remote SSH process. Much less painful to use the native [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) library -- that way you can have just one Transport (a single authenticated connection between client and server) and create a new Channel over it for every individual program you want to run, getting separate stdout/stderr streams and exit status for each rather than needing to try to guess what constitutes shell output, where the boundaries between different remote programs are, etc.

Comment: The OpenSSH command line *can* do those things if you use ControlMaster/ControlSocket functionality, but it's considerably more painful than using a native Python library that exposes the underlying functionality cleanly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unfortunately not. The remote program starts automatically on login and I have no access to be able to make it do anything else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Re paramiko. I did consider using that but this was more of a quick and dirty, and it seemed a reasonably straight forward thing to want to do. I'm happy to reimplement it using whatever to make it work, but at this stage I'm just curious as to what's going on, as it seems strange.

Comment: I'd really need to see a reproducer to be able to come up with a fix I'd be confident for here. If you know enough about what the remote program is doing to provide a script someone could install on the remote side and test with, that would make this a lot easier to provide a definitive and certain answer to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The remote program doesn't seem to have any role in this apart from necessitating that ssh allocates a pty. Even if I log into a regular unix shell somewhere using this code, it does exactly the same thing, and I never get any output either.

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure that if you disable universal newlines and line buffering, but then pass an explicit encoding rather than leaving it to the default, `subprocess` will use text mode. Whether that will solve half your problem (you still don't get newline translation, but you do get Unicode) or just reproduce the original problem (it may just block again) I can't predict, but it seems to be worth trying.

Comment: Second: using `select` with a line-buffered file is inherently a problem. The `TextIOWrapper` may actually be ready to read even though `select` says it isn't, because it's already got the whole next line buffered up and pushed into the decode chain. And the `TextIOWrapper` may not be ready to read even though `select` says it is—if it takes two `_read_chunk` calls to get the next line, it'll make two `_read_chunk` calls, but all `select` told you is that you can make one.

Comment: And one last thing: Does `asyncio.subprocess_exec` work for you? Making async work with code that blocks multiple times (going back to the selector each time) in the middle of a single call is a lot easier than doing the same with non-coro code. (And even if asyncio doesn't just work, it's possible that curio or trio does, but I'm not sure how far you want to chase down that possibility.)

Comment: @abamert subprocess doesn't seem to accept any options for encoding. Is there something I'm missing? Good point re select and line buffered io. I hadn't thought that through. Doesn't resolve the problem though as the non-select way still mysteriously blocks. Thanks also for the hint re doing it async. It's a bit overkill for this, but I'll keep it in mind as something to look into.

Comment: The issue is `communicate` will wait for process to finish. This never happens as the remote command is still running. So will need to read `p.stdout` with a timeout as that will also start to block on waiting for more output from the still running remote process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are library alternatives to subprocess and the SSH binary that are better suited for such tasks.

[parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh):

```
from pssh.pssh2_client import ParalellSSHClient
client = ParallelSSHClient(['HOSTNAME'], user='LOGIN')
output = client.run_command('echo', use_pty=True)

for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Replace `echo` with the command you need to run, or leave as-is if no command is required. The libraries require that something is passed in as command even if the remote side executes something automatically.

See also documentation for the [single host SSHClient](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ssh2_client.html#pssh.ssh2_client.SSHClient.run_command) of the same project.

Per documentation, line parsing and encoding are handled by the library which is also cross-platform.

There are others like paramiko and ssh2-python that are lower level and need more code for the equivalent above - see their respective home pages for examples.

Comment: Thanks for this. This indeed works a lot better and is fairly lightweight. A few issues getting it working with the specific application but it certainly solves the problem of line buffered io.

Comment: I would still love to know what is actually going on in my original example, if anyone has any ideas. I know the data is there ready to read, and includes a new line, so those reads should be coming back. But they aren't. And why there being a pty on the other end should make any difference whatsoever is also a mystery.

Comment: The PTY does matter. It changes the newline character to `\r\n` from `\n` for one thing, in addition to controlling line buffering. Which is why universal newlines is needed and probably why select does not work as expected. Even so, I am not sure if it will correctly realise it should be parsing with windows-style newline characters even on a posix OS. You would need to work directly with `.stdout` on the subprocess either way.